# Is it possible to describe a function that is impossible to implement?

Tags: computer-science, theorem-proving

I am studying Theoretical Computer Science and I encountered this question:

> Give example of a function that takes N as input and outputs (Yes,No) such that there is no Java program that can implement this function.

How would I go about solving this? I must not be understanding this correctly, because I feel like a Java program can always be made from the statement given above.

Comment: Out of context, that makes no sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, any [undecidable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undecidable_problem) decision problem would be a correct answer.

The [halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) is the most famous undecidable problem, and you could use a [Gödel numbering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del_numbering) to encode any input program as a number N.

Answer (score 2):

The halting problem would be an example, given source for a program, a second program cannot tell absolutely if the input program will terminate or not.